# How to print a row without header and NA values in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe called `decision_tree`. I need to print one of the row from the data frame with a condition. for example: Student_id == 100.

```
selected_row <- filter(decision_tree, Student_id=100)
```

But I am getting some weird error.

```
Error: Each variable must be a 1d atomic vector or list.
Problem variables: 'Student_id'

decision_tree <- plyr::ldply(Recommendations, rbind)
decision_tree$Student_id <- select(r_df, Student_id)
colnames(decision_tree) <- c("Recommended Course 1","Recommended Course 2","Recommended Course 3","Recommended Course 4","Recommended Course 5","Student_id")
```

data frame looks like:

[image: data frame]

last field is numeric and other fields are factors with 7 or 9 levels.

Even if I set colnames to NULL. last column will have a Student_id. and first 5 column names would be from 1 to 5

```
structure(list(`Recommended Course 1` = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 
    5L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8L, 2L), .Label = c("p_F20BC", "p_F20DL", 
    "p_F20DP", "p_F20DV", "p_F20GP", "p_F20MA", "p_F20MC", "p_F20RO", 
    "p_F20RS"), class = "factor"), `Recommended Course 2` = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, NA, 9L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 7L), .Label = c("p_F20BC", "p_F20DL", 
    "p_F20DP", "p_F20DV", "p_F20GP", "p_F20MA", "p_F20MC", "p_F20RO", 
    "p_F20RS"), class = "factor"), `Recommended Course 3` = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("p_F20BC", "p_F20DL", 
    "p_F20DP", "p_F20GP", "p_F20MC", "p_F20RO"), class = "factor"), 
        `Recommended Course 4` = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
        NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
        NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Label = "p_F20BC", class = "factor"), 
        Student_id = structure(list(Student_id = c(55L, 68L, 70L, 
        99L, 100L, 101L, 103L, 105L, 106L, 107L)), .Names = "Student_id", row.names = c(NA, 
        10L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("Recommended Course 1", 
    "Recommended Course 2", "Recommended Course 3", "Recommended Course 4", 
    "Student_id"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you just do?: selected_row <- decision_tree[which(decision_tree[,"Student_id"] == 100),]

Comment: @EvanFriedland Yes, that works. But it prints the header and columns with na values too. How to print it like a list? just the cell value. one below another

Comment: Could you paste your desired output? I'm guessing over here.

Comment: @EvanFriedland if you refer above image then for student_id = 55, I need F20RS, F20MC, F20GP and if student_id = 101 then only F20DP. I just need cell values one below another. No need of Column header.

Comment: @EvanFriedland any solution is fine, optimization is not the issue. If conversion to vector or matrix does the job, i m more than happy.

Comment: I compared your dput to the image you posted (which the function was based off of)- working on it now

Comment: What do you expect to show when there is no recommended course for the student id?

Comment: @EvanFriedland  just a text "No course to recommend"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Your dput data is different from your image. The following code produces results of character(0) because there are rows without course recommendations. In the comments let me know how you would like to handle these.

```
decision_tree <- structure(list("Recommended Course 1" = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8L, 2L), .Label = c("p_F20BC", "p_F20DL", "p_F20DP", "p_F20DV", "p_F20GP", "p_F20MA", "p_F20MC", "p_F20RO", "p_F20RS"), class = "factor"), "Recommended Course 2" = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 9L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 7L), .Label = c("p_F20BC", "p_F20DL", "p_F20DP", "p_F20DV", "p_F20GP", "p_F20MA", "p_F20MC", "p_F20RO", "p_F20RS"), class = "factor"), "Recommended Course 3" = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("p_F20BC", "p_F20DL", "p_F20DP", "p_F20GP", "p_F20MC", "p_F20RO"), class = "factor"),  "Recommended Course 4" = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Label = "p_F20BC", class = "factor"), Student_id = structure(list(Student_id = c(55L, 68L, 70L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 103L, 105L, 106L, 107L)), .Names = "Student_id", row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("Recommended Course 1", "Recommended Course 2", "Recommended Course 3", "Recommended Course 4", "Student_id"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")


recommend <- function(StudentID){
  courses <- grep("Course", colnames(decision_tree))
  id <- grep("id", colnames(decision_tree))
  rows <- which(decision_tree[,id] == StudentID)
  x <- decision_tree[rows,courses][!is.na(decision_tree[rows,courses])]
  if(length(x) == 0) {
    paste("No course to recommend")
  } else {
    x
  }
}
recommend(99)
     "p_F20GP" "p_F20RS"

for(i in 1:nrow(decision_tree)){
  print(recommend(decision_tree$Student_id[i,]))
}
[1] "No course to recommend"
[1] "No course to recommend"
[1] "No course to recommend"
[1] "p_F20GP" "p_F20RS"
[1] "No course to recommend"
[1] "No course to recommend"
[1] "No course to recommend"
[1] "No course to recommend"
[1] "p_F20RO" "p_F20DL" "p_F20BC"
[1] "p_F20DL" "p_F20MC" "p_F20DP"
```

Comment: it wont work, I get logical(0) as output. because this code wont work itself. the problem is that the data.frame is not acting normal. data$student_id.Student_id wont work row <- which(data$Student_id.Student_id == StudentID)

Comment: can you post the results of dput(decision_tree[1:10,]) ?

Comment: I have added the output in my question. sorry for the messy output.